# Sharepoint managed metadata permissions

Tags: sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

I have a managed metadata field field on my site which is pointing to a term store.  This looks something like the what I show below.  Is it possible to allow the site owners to tag pages with everything from this term store but to restrict everyone else to tag only what comes below 'Home' (i.e. they can tag pages with 'IT', 'Our services', 'HR' etc but NOT 'home')?

Basically I am 'rolling up' whatever has been tagged with 'Home' onto the home page of my site and I don't want any old user to be able to put stuff onto the home page.

Thanks in advance

```
Internet
   Home
       HR
          What we do
          Opening hours
       IT
          Our services
      etc.
```